# Django save data from calling api in views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i have a views which have a Get and Post request that call to another django project API. But i want to also save the information that i get from the api call.

Project 1 has a Appointment table which has these field `clinic Id`, `time`, and `queueNo`. When i do a Post request to Project 2 to make/create an appointment, when successfully created, it will display those 3 field which i want to save into Project 1 Appointment table database. How do i do it ? My Appointment also has a API made so how do i save it there?

**Here is the code for my view to call api to another django project**

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.GET)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # r.text, r.content, r.url, r.json
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    return HttpResponse('Could not save data')
```

Comment: Where is your data storage interface? Are you using django ORM?

Comment: Django ORM ? from what i know, all im using is just django and django rest framework

Comment: How did you define your `Appointment` table? Did you do it in Python, or directly in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your endpoint in Project 2 returns a JSON response with the fields that you need:

```
{
    "clinicId": 1,
    "time": some-time-string,
    "queueNo": 2
}
```

You can retrieve the response after making the request by calling `r.json()`.

Based on this you can then treat `r.json()` as a dictionary and create the instance using `Appointment.objects.create(**r.json())`. Here's how it might look.

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 200 and request.method == 'POST':
        # Convert response into dictionary and create Appointment
        data = r.json()
        # Construct required dictionary
        appointment_attrs = {
            "clinicId": data["some-key-that-points-to-clinicid"],
            "time": data["some-key-that-points-to-time"],
            "queueNo": data["some-key-that-points-to-queue-num"]
        }
        appointment = Appointment.objects.create(**appointment_attrs)
        # r.text, r.content, r.url, r.json
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.text)

    return HttpResponse('Could not save data')
```

Comment: Thanks ! But sorry to trouble you more, what if the json i get back have 5 fields(a,b,c,d,e) but i only want to save these 3 fields(a,c,e). What do i do then ?  And also if the field name in the json i get back has different name than the field i am saving into, how do i save it ?

Comment: I updated my answer - it's more of a matter of transforming a Python dictionary. So you can use any method, what I've demonstrated above is just one of the ways you can do it - by creating a dictionary with the keys that you need and mapping the data from the `data` dictionary over to the new dictionary. `**` is a way of unpacking Python dictionaries, saves you time from having to type the individual fields out. If this is new to you, you may find more information via Google.

Comment: Just to add on, in this case `Appointment.objects.create(**appointment_attrs)` translates to `Appointment.objects.create(clinicId=<somevalue>, time=<sometime>, queueNo=<somenum>)`

Comment: So its like this `"clinicId": data["clinicId"],` ? Alright will go and try it out. Thank you

Comment: If the they have the same keys then I don't think you need to do that. All you need to do is remove the keys that you don't need from `data` dictionary by using something like `del data["key-that-you-dont-want"]` and do `.create(**data)`.

Comment: i tried  `del data["date"]` and `testget_attrs = {"book": data["book"]` but got this error `line 37, in my_django_view
    "book": data["book"],
KeyError: 'book'`. the `book` is just one of the field i just created for testing. Where did i do wrong ?

Comment: This means that your `data` dictionary doesn't have a key 'book', you might want to print(data) to see what keys you have. In the case where you cannot be sure if you have 'book' as a key, it is always safer to do `data.get("book")` which means from the dictionary `data`, try to retrieve a value with key 'book', if not, return `None`.

Comment: using `print(data)`, the console show this `<QueryDict: {'book': ['Forth'], 'author': ['Tester'], 'date': ['2018-01-10 10:00AM']}>`. When using `print(data.get("book"))`, i get 
`None`

Comment: I'm not sure why it would return `None` if your `data` has a `book` key, did you delete the key in between? In any case - with respect to your initial question, my above solution should be sufficient to achieve what you want.

Comment: Oh, i found my mistake. The api after post request did not return the post value after created, thats why i could not get the value. Thanks again. My bad for these troubles

Answer (score 1):

You first have to extract the data from the responses.
If you're using the `requests` library and the API you're calling is responding in `JSON`, you can do something like `data = r.json()`.

I don't know the structure of your second API's responses, though, but I assume you can then get your fields from the `data` object.

Then it's a matter of saving what you want with whatever database interface you're using. If it's the django ORM, and you have an `Appointement` model somewhere, you can do something like

```
Appointment(
    clinic_id=data["clinic_id"], 
    time=data["time"], 
    queueNo=data["queueNo"]
).save()
```

and you're done...

Comment: I create the table in models.py. Django project 1 is these 3 field on top as stated. `clinic Id`, `time`, and `queueNo`. Django project 2 also has the same table with these 3 field as well as more additional field. I never heard of django ORM but thanks. All i have done for tables is `models.py` `serializer.py` and `views.py`

Comment: "ORM" means "Object-relational mapping". It's how you define and interact with relational database(i.e. SQL) tables in a object oriented way. When you define models and make queries or save data to the database using the django framework, you're using the django ORM. There are others.